Pnpm Install: Failed to parse registry URL
We have a private registry that was using semantic-release to do our npm publish for us
It was working fine but now at version 15 this happens:
Failed to parse registry URL /download/@company/component/1.13.0-next.15/19f083ffb3962e59a8858bb1790e7e746f24d7f4": Invalid URL
I'm not sure what happened there
We've tried:

pnpm store prune
regenerating the lock file
rm node_modules (although this wouldn't work since it happens across machines)


We've replaced our .npmrc's auth_tokens with new ones and it's working again now.
Weird because they haven't expired or anything.

I faced the same issue this morning, everything worked fine yesterday and i didn't change anything.
I have a private package and seem like pnpm has problem resolving the tarball link and its integrity hash
So i had to workaround by resolving the package in pnpm-lock.yaml by hand like so:
I bumped the version of my package.json manually

In my pnpm-lock.yaml


The integrity and tarball can be found by running npm view <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>

This is just a temporary workaround, I hope this will get fixed soon!

Okay this is really similar to me too. We were also using pnpm and initially thought that was the issue first but it wasn't.
The npm view tip is nice though thanks!
